# How can I join 2 sub queries in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 4 tables : T1,T2,T3,T4

```
--T1:               
    Info_Id | fname | lname
    101     | rol   | lum 

--T2:
    Acc_id | acc_info_id | acc_property
    01     | 101         |  land       

--T3:
    Bill_id | status    | amt_2_paid |  Acc_id
    123     |  UNPAID   |  200       | 01   

--T4:  
    Accnt_bill | OR      |  Acc_id
    123        | 01234   |  01
```

I have two sub queries, shown below:

```
SELECT 
      fname,
      lname 
  FROM T1 
 WHERE Info_id IN(SELECT Acc_id FROM T2 WHERE acc_info_id = '01234')
```

The first sub query displays only `fname` and `lname`:

```
SELECT 
      status,
      amt_2_paid 
 FROM T3 
WHERE Bill_id IN(SELECT Accnt_id FROM t4 WHERE OR = '01234')
```

The second subquery displays only `status` and `amt_2_paid`:

My question is how to join two sub queries in order to display the value of `fname`, `name`, `status`, and `amt_2_paid` when I input the OR no.

Comment: Please specify the RDBMS that you're using.

Comment: Also please specify how the fields relate, since the naming is a mess. And next time, **please** post table schemas that match your sql queries. The columns in the table description don't match the names in the query. That's just sloppy.

Comment: SELECT t1, fname, t1.lname, t3.status, t3.amt_2_paid FROM t1 INNER JOIN T2 on t1.info_id = t2.acc_info_id INNER JOIN T3 on  t2.acc_id = t3.acc_id

Comment: I used postgres database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just combine all your tables with one query using `INNER JOIN`. See below:

```
SELECT 
      T1.fname, 
      T1.lname, 
      T3.status, 
      T3.amt_2_paid
FROM T1 
INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.Info_id=T2.acc_info_id
INNER JOIN T3 ON T2.Acc_id=T3.Acc_id
INNER JOIN T4 ON T3. Bill_id=T4.Accnt_bill
WHERE T4.[OR] ='01234'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT fname, name, status,amt_2_paid 
 FROM T3 
 INNER JOIN t4 ON t3.Bill_id = t4.Accnt_bill
 INNER JOIN t2 ON t2.Acc_id = t3.Acc_id
 INNER JOIN t1 ON t1.Info_id = t2.Info_Id
 WHERE t4."OR" = '01234'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    t1.fname,
    t1.lname,
    t3.status,
    t3.amt_2_paid
FROM 
    t1 
    INNER JOIN t2 on t1.info_id = t2.acc_info_id
    INNER JOIN t3 on t2.acc_id = t3.acc_id
    INNER JOIN t4 on t3.bill_id = t4.accnt_bill
WHERE 
    t4.[or] = '01234'
```